# Analyzing the type of triangle using Java

Tags: java, class, if-statement, logic, bluej

The code below is supposed to analyze the type of a triangle based on the angles entered by the user in the terminal. However, in the first if statement although I set it to `(a+b+c==d)` - still, in the terminal if I enter 180, 1, 1 - instead of stopping the execution and printing `Triangle is not possible.`, it instead says the triangle is isosceles. It's surely a mistake on my part. But I am a noob, so please correct my statements.

```
/**
 * @date 20/4/2014
 */ 


import java.io.*;
public class Triangleanglederivation
{
       public static void main (String args[])throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);
        int a,b,c,d; 
        d=180;
        System.out.println("Enter the three sides of the triangle:");
        a=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        b=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        c=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());        
        if(a+b+c==d)
            System.out.println("Triangle is possible.");    
        if((a==b)&&(b==c)&&(c==a))
            System.out.println("The triangle is equilateral.");
        else if((a==b)||(b==c)||(c==a))
            System.out.println("The triangle is isosceles.");
        else if((a!=b)&&(b!=c)&&(c!=a))
            System.out.println("The triangle is scalene.");
        else
            System.out.println("Triangle is not possible.");
    }
}
```

#### Fix

```
if((a==b)&&(b==c)&&(c==a)&&(a+b+c==d))
  System.out.println("The triangle is equilateral.");
else if(((a==b)||(b==c)||(c==a))&&(a+b+c==d))
  System.out.println("The triangle is isosceles.");
else if((a!=b)&&(b!=c)&&(c!=a)&&(a+b+c==d))
  System.out.println("The triangle is scalene.");
else
  System.out.println("Triangle is not possible.");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your checks for the triangle being equilateral, isosceles, and scalene are being applied regardless of whether the triangle is possible or not.  You need to either add the possibility check `(a+b+c==d)` to each of those using `&&` or nest the if/else such that they only happen when the `if (a+b+c==d)` has succeeded.

Comment: Possible triangle should be validated by **a+b > c** AND **a+c > b** AND **b+c > a**